# Stub a function with arguments

Tags: javascript, sinon

I'm trying to stub a method which takes arguments.

I normally use my object like so:

```
const res = await Obj.find('admin', 'type');
```

This works. It either returns null or an object.

I normally stub this like so:

```
sandbox.stub(Obj.prototype, 'find', function () {
  return Promise.resolve({ id: 123 });
});
```

I'd like to stub it so that the arguments are taken into account. I've been reading http://sinonjs.org/docs/#stubs and it's supposed to look like the following:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(Obj.prototype.find);
stub.withArgs('admin', 'type')
  .returns(Promise.resolve({ id: 123 }));
stub.withArgs('user', 'type').returns(null);
```

I however get the error:

```
 TypeError: Attempted to wrap undefined property undefined as function
  at Object.wrapMethod (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/util/core.js:114:29)
  at Object.stub (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/stub.js:67:26)
```

`console.log(Obj.prototype.find);` results in:

```
[Function: find]
```

Comment: What is at line 67, column 26 of stub.js?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Arghhh, I was nearly correct. Below is working code:

```
const stub = sinon.stub(Obj.prototype, 'find');
stub.withArgs('admin', 'type')
  .returns(Promise.resolve(new User({ id: 123 })));
stub.withArgs('user', 'type').returns(null);
```